# Column value for rails child model inside parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

```
Reservation has_many :bookings, has_many :extras, :through => :bookings
Booking belongs_to :extra, belongs_to :reservation
Extra has_many :bookings, has_many :reservations, :through => :bookings
```

How do you get the column value of the Extra model from inside the Reservation model by id (e.g Extra model has a daily_rate column and i want the value for that column for an Extra with ID of 3)

```
reservation.rb

some_variable = Extra.find(3) ......
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to find all reservations for Extra model with ID of 3?

Comment: I want to use the value of *daily_rate* of the Extra with an id of 3 to calculate something. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did you try `Extra.find(3).daily_rate` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works well.

Answer (score 0):

You use the join table you listed (Booking) to fetch records between the two tables. Rails does this implicitly so you just make your call as: `Extra.find(3).reservations`

To go from the reservations model to find the extra with id 3 you would do:

```
obj = Reservation.find(whatever_record_id_you_are_using).extras.where(id: 3)
```

Comment: Perhaps my original questions wasn't very clear. As my response above to @imechemi above states all i need is the value of 'daily_rate' for the Extra with id of 3. That value is needed for a calculated value in the new Reservation i'm creating. Also that extra with id = 3 already exists.